# How to aggregate by geo using elasticsearch_dsl?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

If I have customer locations stored as geo_point datatype (latitude/longitude) and i need to determine doc_count grouped by the geo_point location, what is the elasticsearch_dsl syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Below query would give you what you need:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "myaggs":{  
         "terms":{  
            "script":"def x = String.valueOf(doc['location'].lat).concat(',')+ String.valueOf(doc['location'].lon); return x;"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Although I have the above query, I'd suggest you to rethink what your requirement is as geo-point aggregations would generally make sense ***only*** when you aggregate using ***range*** from a particular `geo_point` for e.g. `search gas stations which are near 100 miles around a house you have Amsterdam`.

You can then make use of aggregations that are specifically built to handle `geo_point` datatype. I personally feel query I've provided, although works correctly, would not make any sense or I doubt if it would be of any help (although I hope it helps and I'm proved wrong).

Please go through the below links so that you would create aggregations for correct use-cases or at-least will make you rethink about your current use-case.

[Geo Distance Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geodistance-aggregation.html) and [Geo Hash-grid Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html)

Hope it helps!